# How do I extract edges that contain a certain label in a dot file?

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, dot, pydot

My objective is to extract paths that contain a certain label within a dot file. However, this is the first time I have worked with a dot file. I have no idea how to extract the labels of a dot file using Python. For instance, in the dot file below, I want to extract the path that belong to the label "V1". Here is my dot file -

```
digraph "MVICFG" {
    label="MVICFG";
/* Generating Nodes */
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label="main";
        "6" [label="4294967294::Entry::main"];
        "2" [label="0::  %1 = alloca i32, align 4"];
        "3" [label="0::  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4"];
        "4" [label="0::  %2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0)), !dbg !13"];
        "5" [label="4::  ret i32 0, !dbg !14"];
        "7" [label="4294967293::Exit::main"];
        "11" [label="3::  %1 = alloca i32, align 4"];
        "12" [label="3::  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4"];
        "13" [label="3::  %2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0)), !dbg !13"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_9 {
        label="External_Node_Func";
        "10" [label="4294967294::External_Node"];
    }

/* Generating Edges */
        "2" -> "3" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V1"];
        "3" -> "4" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V1"];
        "6" -> "2" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = pink, label="V1::Virtual"];
        "5" -> "7" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = pink, label="V1,V2::Virtual"];
        "4" -> "5" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V1"];
        "6" -> "11" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = pink, label="V2::Virtual"];
        "13" -> "5" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V2"];
        "11" -> "12" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V2"];
        "12" -> "13" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V2"];
}
```

Here is what I've done -
I looked into a popular Python library that worked with dot files, called pydot. I wrote the following code, but couldn't get to the stage of extracting labels.

```
import pydot

dot_string = """digraph "MVICFG" {
    label="MVICFG";
/* Generating Nodes */
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label="main";
        "6" [label="4294967294::Entry::main"];
        "2" [label="0::  %1 = alloca i32, align 4"];
        "3" [label="0::  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4"];
        "4" [label="0::  %2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0)), !dbg !13"];
        "5" [label="4::  ret i32 0, !dbg !14"];
        "7" [label="4294967293::Exit::main"];
        "11" [label="3::  %1 = alloca i32, align 4"];
        "12" [label="3::  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4"];
        "13" [label="3::  %2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0)), !dbg !13"];
    }
    subgraph cluster_9 {
        label="External_Node_Func";
        "10" [label="4294967294::External_Node"];
    }

/* Generating Edges */
        "2" -> "3" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V1"];
        "3" -> "4" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V1"];
        "6" -> "2" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = pink, label="V1::Virtual"];
        "5" -> "7" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = pink, label="V1,V2::Virtual"];
        "4" -> "5" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V1"];
        "6" -> "11" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = pink, label="V2::Virtual"];
        "13" -> "5" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V2"];
        "11" -> "12" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V2"];
        "12" -> "13" [arrowhead = normal, penwidth = 1.0, color = black, label="V2"];
}

"""

graphs = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_string)
graph = graphs[0]
```

Update 1:

If I am looking for the edges corresponding to the label "V1", I'd like this type of output -

```
"2" -> "3" 
"3" -> "4" 
"4" -> "5"
```

I can get that from the code that SultanOrazbayev posted by adding the following line -

```
G_sub.edges
```

Comment: I tried to do something similar a few years ago and found graphviz great for visualization but poor for analysis. I'd suggest trying NetworkX instead.

Comment: What does it mean to extract an edge?  Remove it from the graph?  Remove all other edges?  Grep it?  Do you want an exact match (e.g. only "V1"  or "V1blah blah" also?  Is Python a requirement?

Comment: I just need to know which edges correspond to a label. An exact or approximate match will do. I do need it in Python. I believe there are Python libraries that will do it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have made the changes under Update 1.  By approximate, I meant any label that had the string I was looking for would be okay for me. The dot file was created using a tool called Hydrogen. I am not sure if there was any "pre-defined structured input".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `dot` file is named `test.dot`, the following procedure will use `networkx` to load the `dot` file (this requires `pydot` to be installed also), and then filter the edges, returning a subgraph with the desired edges.

```py
from networkx import subgraph_view
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import read_dot

# load the dot file
G = read_dot('test.dot')

# define the function to filter edges
def filter_edge(source, target, edge_id):
    """Note this function hardcodes the desired edge label,
    also note the nested quoting of the label to match the raw data."""
    if G[source][target][edge_id].get('label')=='"V1"':
        return True

G_sub = subgraph_view(G, filter_edge=filter_edge)
print(G_sub)
# MultiDiGraph named 'MVICFG' with 10 nodes and 3 edges
```

If you also want to remove the `isolates`, then use the relevant `networkx` function:

```py
from networkx import isolates, MultiDiGraph

# make a modifiable copy of the graph
G_sub = MultiDiGraph(G_sub)

# identify which nodes to remove
remove_nodes = list(isolates(G_sub))

G_sub.remove_nodes_from(remove_nodes)
print(G_sub)
# MultiDiGraph named 'MVICFG' with 4 nodes and 3 edges
```

Note that the result of `isolates` is stored in a `list`, this is to avoid iterating over a graph that is being modified, see this [PR](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/6268) and associated [GH issue](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2717).